# Extract keywords from url using queries in google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, substring

Write a **query** to extract the keywords from the URL column.
Can anyone please help me to extract keywords from the URL column using the query function in google sheets?

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=games&c=apps (Keyword: games)
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=football%20match%20score%20app&c=apps (Keyword: football, match, score, app)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A2, "=(.*)&c=apps"), "%20"))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please help me to solve it using query function in sheets like =QUERY(keywords!$A$1:$A$2, "select .......)